# eledmac problem: "linespread" and space between familiar footnotes

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing, eledmac

With `eledmac`, how can I increase the space between familiar footnotes in two columns and reduce the "linespread" inside the footnotes?

In the image, the footnotes 6, 23 and 33 look odd (more distance between lines of the same footnote than between footnotes)

[image]

EDITS: (1) I've added `bhooknoteX` as suggested by **Maïeul**, but it seems it's not working. (2) I hope this works as a mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{.4em}
\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage{eledmac}
\foottwocolX{A}
\renewcommand*{\footfootmarkA}{\arabic{footnoteA}.\tabto{0.45cm}}
\hangindentX[A]{0.45cm}
\footparagraphX{B}
\renewcommand*{\bodyfootmarkB}{\textsuperscript{\alph{footnoteB}}}
\renewcommand*{\footfootmarkB}{\textbf{\alph{footnoteB}}. }
\prenotesX{5mm}
\afterruleX[A]{2mm}

% It seems that this line does nothing:
\bhooknoteX[A]{\setlength{\parskip}{.4em}\linespread{.8}}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}

\begin{document}

some random text some random text some random text.\footnoteA{some random
text some random text some random text.}\footnoteB{some random text some
random text some random text.}some random text some random text some random
text.\footnoteA{some random text some random text some random 
text.}\footnoteB{some random text some random text some random text.}some 
random text some random text some random text.\footnoteA{some random text some
random text some random text.}\footnoteB{some random text some random 
text some random text.}some random text some random text some random 
text.\footnoteA{some random text some random text some random 
text.}\footnoteB{some random text some random text some random text.}some 
random text some random text some random text.\footnoteA{some random 
text some random text some random text.}\footnoteB{some random text 
some random text some random text.}

some random text some random text some random text.\footnoteA{some random
text some random text some random text.}\footnoteB{some random text some
random text some random text.}some random text some random text some random
text.\footnoteA{some random text some random text some random 
text.}\footnoteB{some random text some random text some random text.}some 
random text some random text some random text.\footnoteA{some random text some
random text some random text.}\footnoteB{some random text some random 
text some random text.}some random text some random text some random 
text.\footnoteA{some random text some random text some random 
text.}\footnoteB{some random text some random text some random text.}some 
random text some random text some random text.\footnoteA{some random 
text some random text some random text.}\footnoteB{some random text 
some random text some random text.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please, provides a full mwe. I think you should use \bhooknoteX to insert code to modify the linespread.

Comment: Maïeul : Added a mwe. I've used `\bhooknoteX` but it's not working (or I don't know how to use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is provoked by the tabto command. I don't know exactly what does it do, but looking to its code, I can underatand it create linespread problem in two column mode.

Juste replace

```
\renewcommand*{\footfootmarkA}{\arabic{footnoteA}.\tabto{0.45cm}}
```

by

```
\renewcommand*{\footfootmarkA}{\hbox to 0.45cm{\arabic{footnoteA}.\hfill}}
```

Comment: Without `tabto` the output is nice enough (the notes use the same `linespread` of the body text), and I accept this answer for the current problem. I still can't control the linespread of the notes, though (don't know how to use `bhooknoteX`).

Comment: for the other problem, that is because bhooknoteX is not implemented for two columns note. Please open an issue.

Comment: open in https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/413

Comment: issue corrected, in https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/2.4.0-2.5.1.zip, but as I am not sure of what you need, I am not sure that is the good tols for you.

Comment: I want to reduce the linespread in the notes, to avoid the problem showed in the images: In the notes with two lines, the second line is nearer to the next note than to the first line of the same note. That's not nice.
Sorry but I don't know how to use the files you've linked.

Comment: please read https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/#debug-and-feature-requests to know.